Why won't my image move below the text on smaller screens?
I've been trying to make my code mobile friendly using tailwind css and their responsive layout and design. However, when integrating it into my code, the image 'bot.png' will not move below the text beside it; rather, it just shrinks and shrinks until the image dissapears. This is not the intended outcome, as I want the image to shrink based on the screen size but move below the text if it can't look clean with both the text and image on the same row.
<!-- Main Section (Hero Section) -->
    <section class="py-20 bg-black">
        <div class="max-w-5xl mx-auto flex flex-col lg:flex-row items-center px-6">
            <!-- Text Content on the Left -->
            <div class="lg:w-3/4 text-left">
                <h1 class="title-lg text-violet-500 font-bold mb-6">Unlock the Future of Hotel Customer Service</h1>
                <p class="text-lg md:text-xl lg:text-2xl text-purple-400 mb-8">Our AI-powered hotel chatbot revolutionizes customer service by answering your guests' questions instantly and accurately, 24/7. Enhance their experience and boost your revenue.</p>
                <div class="flex left-0 lg:justify-start space-x-4">
                    <a href="#how-it-works" class="button-lg border border-fuchsia-400 rounded-full hover:bg-fuchsia-400/50 transition transform hover:scale-105">See How It Works</a>
                </div>
            </div>

    
            <!-- Image on the Right -->
            <div class="lg:w-1/3 flex justify-center lg:justify-end mt-8 lg:mt-0 ml-6">
                <img src="bot.png" alt="Chatbot" class="rounded-lg shadow-lg w-full h-auto">
            </div>

    </section>

This is the section that I have been trying to implement mobile friendly code to start, but it just won't work, for the problem above. I tried changing the style of the whole html file too, but it does not seem to change anything. Below is the html file style.
<style>
        html {
            scroll-behavior: smooth;
        }

        /* Responsive button and text sizes for various screen widths */
        @media (min-width: 24px) {
            .button-lg {
                padding: 0.75rem 2.5rem;
                font-size: 1.25rem;
            }

            .text-balance {
                font-size: 1.25rem;
            }

            .title-lg {
                font-size: 3.5rem;
            }
        }

        @media (min-width: 24px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
            .button-lg {
                padding: 0.75rem 1.5rem;
                font-size: 1.125rem;
            }

            .text-balance {
                font-size: 1.125rem;
            }

            .title-lg {
                font-size: 2.75rem;
            }
        }

        @media (max-width: 24px) {
            .button-lg {
                padding: 0.75rem 1rem;
                font-size: 1rem;
            }

            .text-balance {
                font-size: 1rem;
            }

            .title-lg {
                font-size: 2.25rem;
            }

            /* Navbar responsive */
            .navbar-items {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                align-items: center;
                gap: 0.75rem;
                margin-top: 1rem;
            }

            .navbar-items a {
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
            }
        }
    </style>


add a flex-wrap class to this <div class="max-w-5xl mx-auto flex flex-col lg:flex-row items-center px-6"> and check the result.
